# Ubuntu 14.04 Bluetooth not working on Lenovo Laptop

Tags: 14.04, drivers, bluetooth, freeze

I am running ubuntu 14.04 on my lenovo g510 laptop. I have issues with the bluetooth.

Here is what i did: 
I installed the bluetooth and bluez and all other bluez packages using apt-get. Then, I was unsuccessful in my efforts and then I copied the .hex file from windows and used [hex2hcd](https://github.com/jessesung/hex2hcd/) tool to convert it to hcd and copied the same to /lib/firmware/. I was then able to connect to the bluetooth, but the audio quality of my JBL bluetooth earphones was worse.
I then updated the bluez and downloaded a bunch of bluez packages.

```
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-hcidump bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev  libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3
```

Since then, I am not able to even start the bluetooth device. If i try to restart the bluetooth service (sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart), it will freeze. I am now unable to turn on or turn off the bluetooth. When i open the "Bluetooth" from "System Settings", It shows, "Bluetooth is Disabled" beneath the bluetooth turn on/off switch. I am unable to enable the bluetooth.

In addition, when i try to shutdown, i see  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krTZU.jpg) screen and ubuntu freezes at this point.

Additional Info: This is the output of the command  **lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0611]
Kernel driver in use: wl
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174f:114f Syntek 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This is the output of **dmesg**

```
[   25.142394] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   25.144424] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   25.144433] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   25.144436] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   25.144442] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   25.501897] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   25.501898] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   25.501905] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   27.100960] Bluetooth: firmware loaded
[   48.821537] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   48.821549] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   48.821555] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

here is the firmware:

```
:~$ ls /lib/firmware/brcm/*.hcd
/lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd
```

I am looking forward to overcome the 3 issues as mentioned above, i.e bluetooth not able to be turned on/off, bluetooth service hangs when attempted to start/stop and ubuntu not shutting down.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

**EDIT 1**: in the syslog, i notice the following,

```
Aug 21 09:47:44 ubuntu-user bluetoothd[421]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
Aug 21 09:47:44 ubuntu-user bluetoothd[421]: hci0 Load Connection Parameters failed: Unknown Command (0x01)
Aug 21 09:47:47 ubuntu-user NetworkManager[794]: <warn> bluez error getting default adapter: Method "DefaultAdapter" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Manager" doesn't exist
Aug 21 09:48:01 ubuntu-user pulseaudio[2018]: [pulseaudio] bluetooth-util.c: org.bluez.Manager.GetProperties() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetProperties" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Manager" doesn't exist
Aug 21 09:48:04 ubuntu-user blueproximity[2328]: started.
Aug 21 09:48:05 ubuntu-user dbus[412]: [system] Activating service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' (using servicehelper)
Aug 21 09:48:05 ubuntu-user blueman-mechanism: Starting blueman-mechanism 
Aug 21 09:48:05 ubuntu-user dbus[412]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
Aug 21 09:48:05 ubuntu-user blueman-mechanism: loading RfKill 
Aug 21 09:48:05 ubuntu-user blueman-mechanism: loading Config 
Aug 21 09:48:05 ubuntu-user blueman-mechanism: loading Ppp 
Aug 21 09:48:05 ubuntu-user blueman-mechanism: loading Network 
Aug 21 09:48:05 ubuntu-user kernel: [   46.871717] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Aug 21 09:48:05 ubuntu-user kernel: [   46.871728] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Aug 21 09:48:05 ubuntu-user kernel: [   46.871733] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Aug 21 09:48:35 ubuntu-user blueman-mechanism: Exiting
```

Comment: What is the kernel version?

Comment: Kernel version is 3.13.0-93-generic

Comment: Upgrade the kernel to 4.4 by `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial`. You will need to rename or copy the firmware file to `BCM.hcd`.